# React native Video not show preview of list of videos on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video for video player but it not show preview of list of videos.

Please check this

```
<Video
    ref={ref => this._video = ref}
    source={{ uri: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" }}
     resizeMode={'cover'}
     repeat={true}
     paused = {true}
     style={{
         height: 200,
         width: 200,
     }}
     onLoad={() => {
         this._video.seek(2);
     }} />


    <Video
        ref={ref => this._video = ref}
        source={{ uri: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" }}
         resizeMode={'cover'}
         repeat={true}
         paused = {true}
         style={{
             height: 200,
             width: 200,
         }}
         onLoad={() => {
             this._video.seek(2);
         }} />
   <Video
        ref={ref => this._video = ref}
        source={{ uri: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" }}
         resizeMode={'cover'}
         repeat={true}
         paused = {true}
         style={{
             height: 200,
             width: 200,
         }}
         onLoad={() => {
             this._video.seek(2);
         }} />
```

It show preview of first video only.

If it is not possible, then can any one please suggest me any other library for video preview from url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution to this issue by adding unique "ref" in each  tag

```
<Video
    ref={ref => this._video1 = ref}
    source={{ uri: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" }}
     resizeMode={'cover'}
     repeat={true}
     paused = {true}
     style={{
         height: 200,
         width: 200,
     }}
     onLoad={() => {
         this._video1.seek(2);
     }} />


    <Video
        ref={ref => this._video2 = ref}
        source={{ uri: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" }}
         resizeMode={'cover'}
         repeat={true}
         paused = {true}
         style={{
             height: 200,
             width: 200,
         }}
         onLoad={() => {
             this._video2.seek(2);
         }} />
```

Thanks!